# Where do apps developed using Qt save their settings when using QSettings in macOS?

Tags: macos, qt, settings

Suppose I have an app and I used the following code to save settings:

```
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("orgname");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("appname");

QSettings settings;
settings.setValue("options/color","green");
```

What is the name of the resulting settings file and where is it saved in Mac OS 10.7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be

```
$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.orgname.appname.plist
```

See: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsettings.html#locations-where-application-settings-are-stored

Comment: I could not find it there and the documentation only gives the path for Mac OS X versions 10.2 and 10.3. I have 10.7.

Comment: My bad, the file was hidden. Thanks.

Comment: Where does it store it for 10.10 for system scope?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to know it at runtime, regardless of platform:

```
QString settingPath = yourSettings.fileName();
```

Comment: On Windows the default is to use the registry though, not a file.

Comment: And it will give you the path of the registry.

Comment: I forgot the right name of the app, that I used with QSettings, and thus couldn't find the plist in the right place. But this solution is universal!